# Rails 3 Sunspot solr search within bounds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, ruby-on-rails-plugins, sunspot

I have a question to ask regarding the new Sunspot/solr feature: [restriction with near](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/classes/Sunspot/DSL/RestrictionWithNear.html#M000116)
I have (via the google geocoding API) the viewport and the bounds which are latitude/longitude coordinates of the southwest and northeast corners of a bounding box. I want Sunspot/Solr to search within this bounding box but I haven't figured it out yet. So my question is: ***Is it possible to make Solr (or via any of the solr plugins) capable for searches within a bounding box? If yes, how?***

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a `lat` and `lng` field of type trie double, and then do two range queries (one for a lat range, one for a lng range).

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  seachable do
     double :latitude
     double :longitude
  end
end

# search
Product.search do
  with :latitude, 36.5667..80.4553 
  with :longitude, 76.4556..67.9987
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) To get it straight I have to do define in searchable do double :lat, :trie => true double :lng, :trie => true end And in my search I just do with :lat, 36.5667..80.4553 with :lng, 76.4556..67.9987 ?? Was that so simple?? I feel stupid now :P P.S. The coords provided I have NO idea where they lead to :P

Comment: Yep, that's what I was suggesting exactly : )

Comment: Nice :) Also do you have any idea if there will be any future implementation of Sunspot/solr to do polygon area searches? Are you aware of a plugin or something that solr uses to do that? Thanks again! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Sunspot supports spartial search using Geohash, see [RestrictionWithNear](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/classes/Sunspot/DSL/RestrictionWithNear.html). But you can only use the predifined distance (though `:precision`).

```ruby
# model
# lat: decimal
# lng: decimal
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  seachable do
    location :location do
      Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(lat, lng)
    end
  end
end

# search
Product.search do
  # near(lat, lng)
  with(:location).near(76.4556, 67.9987, :precision => 3)
end
```

---

Sparcial is [added](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch) in solr starting from 3.1, I cannot find correspondng DSL in sunspot, but you can always use `adjust_solr_params` to add customized parameters:

```ruby
Product.search do
  adjust_solr_params do |params|
    parmas[:fq] << '{!geofilt pt=74.4556,67.9987 sfield=location d=5}'
  end
end
```

You have to use Solr 3.1 (the bundled solr in sunspot is 1.4), and index field location like

```ruby
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string(:location, :as => :location) { [lat,lng].join(',') }
  end
end
```

Also the field type needs to be added into schema.xml. (An example, I have not tried it myself)

```xml
<types>
  ...
  <fieldType name="geo" class="solr.LatLonType" omitNorms="true"/>
</types>
<fields>
  ...
  <field name="location" stored="false" termVectors="false" type="geo" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
</fields>
```